# How to set informations of current song to iPhone lock screen with JS

Tags: javascript, iphone, html, cordova

I got an audio element on my page and i want to set the informations (title, artist, album etc.) to the iPhone lock screen while playing. (With JS)

How is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible just with Javascript. If you're just running Javascript in a browser it has no access to the lock screen functionality.

**Edit**:

Since you're using PhoneGap, it is possible. You need to access the `MPNowPlayingInfoCenter` class. There is at least one plugin, AudioStream, that gives you access. Check it out here: https://github.com/liip/phonegap-plugins-audiostream