# PhoneGap/Cordova html5 audio (jPlayer) album art on Lock Screen

Tags: ios, html, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I have a HTML5 Application for audio playing. It uses jPlayer for playing the audio on html5. When I bundle it within phonegap, iOS is itself fetches the audio stream and shows its navigation icons on the lock screen. Now I want to push a image to that lock screen notification. I have followed this link 
[How to set informations of current song to iPhone lock screen with JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10871031/how-to-set-informations-of-current-song-to-iphone-lock-screen-with-js)
https://github.com/ChoiZ/NowPlaying/tree/phonegap2

Is there any plugin available for this. 
I dont want to create a new media object with audio src but just want to pass image to the current lockscreen song.

Comment: You will need to create your own plugin for it

Comment: have you found a solution yet?